# Please help! I am trying to get input from a file with spaces I keep getting infinite loop. C programming

Tags: c, file

I am trying to read every word in a file and print it to the screen. I want The program to accept spaces but it gives me an infinite loop when I use this %[^\n]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    FILE *DoThis;
    DoThis = fopen("Encrypppc.txt", "r");
    char word2[48];
    while(!feof(DoThis)){

        fscanf(DoThis,"%47[^\n]s",word2);
        printf("%s\n", word2);
        
    }
return 0;
}
```

Try to create a file and input spaces in the first sentence. It gives an infinite loop in the first sentence when there's space so it never reaches eof.

Comment: Did you read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), in particular the documentation of [fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) ? Did you read books like [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and [the Dragon book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book_(computer_science))? Did you read the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...)? Of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) ...)?

Comment: What about  [UTF-8](https://utf8everywhere.org/) encoding, it is everywhere in 2021? What about a line like `Être ou ne pas être §` inside your file? Are you allowed to use C code generators like [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex) ?

Comment: If you can use a recent  [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, use it with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Remember that **StackOverflow is *not* a do-my-homework website**

Comment: Read also the wikipage on [finite state machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) - it is relevant to your problem. And a test on `feof` makes sense *only* after some input (i.e. *after* `fscanf`, not before). Are you allowed to use [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) ?

Comment: I suggest you test for an open failure in `fopen()`.  If the file name is misspelled or not in the current default directory or opened for writing in another process or maybe a few other situations, you'll get a `NULL` return value from `fopen()`.  Trying to do I/O with a null FILE* pointer usually results in a segment violation, but there are no guarantees of anything in an "undefined behavior" situation.

Comment: You could also download the source code then take inspiration of [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) projects like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), or open source projects like  [Jansson](http://jansson.org/) - all are solving your problem inside their code!

Comment: You could also look inside the source code of [sash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stand-alone_shell). It also solves your problem

Comment: @MikeHousky: I gave several hyperlinks to help the OP

Comment: You are trying to use `feof` to predict whether a future read operation will suceed. It can't do that. You need to check if `fscanf` succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer I supposed to
add a space in the fscanf function.
this is what gives me the infinite loop

```
fscanf(DoThis,"%47[^\n]s",word2);
```

after I add a space before the sign % there's no infinite loop and the loop stops at EOF

```
fscanf(DoThis," %47[^\n]s",word2);
```

notice the change

Comment: It's the 's' after the ] in your format that's causing the problem.  The ']' is the format type, so the 's' tells fscanf to match an 's' in the input.  That 's' does NOT match the \n that ends the first line, so the \n isn't consumed and is there to stop the next fscanf.

Answer (score 1):

You have an 's' that doesn't belong in the format string.  Try this:

```
fscanf("%47[^\n]%*c", word2);
```

That will get you past the failure to read the end of file and on to the next problem.  I added the %*c format to read and ignore the next character (either a \n newline or the end of file).  That does (more precisely) what you accomplish with the leading space (which discards all spaces and tabs up to the next nonblank character.)

That "next problem" is the one mentioned in comment that `feof()` only goes true after an attempt to read past the end of file.  You'll see your last line twice.  The leading space in the format might work for you, but a better solution is to use the return value from `fscanf()` to tell you if the input read anything:

```
while (1)
{
    int n = fscanf("%47[\n]%*c", word2);
    if (n != 1) break;
    ...do something with word2
}
```

The `?scanf` functions return the number of fields successfully converted and stored.  There's only one such field in your format, so the return will be 1 whenever the input succeeded, or something else if it didn't. (Both 0 and `EOF` are possible returns, depending on the state of the file beforehand.)

Comment: PS: If you don't like using `break`, you can put the whole scanf and result test into a while condition:  `while (1 == fscanf(....blah...))`.  It's a common C pattern to avoid break, and also to avoid an extra fscanf() before the loop.